# Maximizing a WPF Page and fitting contents

Tags: c#, wpf, window, maximize

How do I maximize a WPF window without the contents getting all messed up?

I want to design it to start maximized and the contents to fit as I designed the form?

I read about setting the hight and width settings with a *, but I'm not too sure on how to apply it, as I have tried and it doesn't seem to work.

The code in the answer below works, but how do i use that for my own app??? What is it that makes the buttons and labels etc auto-resizing?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality in your application you can achieve by using `Grid` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx))

Here is simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="AppMaximize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Row1Col1" />
        <Button Content="Row1Col1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />

        <Label Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Label Background="Green" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Label Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Label Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

[image]